# localStorage some quando atualizo a página

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html5

Estou a fazer a seguinte operação:

Pego o texto digitado em uma `<textarea>` e faço um `push()` para adicioná-lo no array; logo depois salvo no *localStorage*. Recupero o valores, faço um `split()` a via *AngularJS* adiciono na `<ul>`.

Até aqui tudo bem, mas quando atualizo a página os dados somem. A função começa a adicionar os valores na posição inicial do array por que  ele está vazio.

O que estou a fazer de errado?

**JS**

```
(function  () {
    'use strict';

    var statusList = [];

    angular.module('appStatus'[])
      .controller('CreateNewStatusController', 
        function CreateNewStatusController($scope) {

        $scope.saveStatus = function () {
            statusList.push(document.getElementById('status_text').value);

            localStorage.setItem('dbStatus', statusList);

            console.log(statusList);

        }

    });

    angular.module('listAllStatus', [])
       .controller('ListStatusController', 
        function ListStatusController ($scope) {

            $scope.status = localStorage.getItem('dbStatus').split(',');
            console.log(localStorage.getItem('dbStatus'));
    });
}());
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="content" style="margin-top: 60px;">
    <ul ng-controller="ListStatusController">
        <li ng-repeat="s in status">
            {{ s }}
        </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
```

Comment: O localStorage guarda strings. Estás a passar-lhe uma array... Devias fazer `localStorage.setItem('dbStatus', JSON.stringify(statusList);` e depois `$scope.status = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('dbStatus'));`, se bem que não acho que seja esse o problema.

Comment: @Sergio, eu sei, mas ele está guardando os dados, ou seja, o problema não é esse como salientou

Comment: Não falta uma virgula aqui `angular.module('appStatus'[])` a separar os argumentos?